# How to display N number of Backward relationship in Django templates?

Tags: django, django-template-filters

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {% for product in categories.product_set.all %}
        <h1> {{ product.name }} </h1>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to show 10 products instead of all in template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) filter that you can use in templates:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {% for product in categories.product_set.all|slice:":10" %}
        <h1> {{ product.name }} </h1>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Solve, but slice:"10" will use in inner loop

Comment: Edited my answer